# Selecting ID of a element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML code snippet.

```
<li my-id="10" class="my-class">test-1</li>
<li my-id="15" class="my-class">test-2</li>
<li my-id="20" class="my-class">test-3</li>
```

Can anybody help me how to get the id of the above one html element when a click event is occur. When explaining more, I have following code in jquery. When a user clicks on any of the above element I need to extract the id corresponds to same element. I use following code in jQuery.

```
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
var ids = e.targetElement.attr('my-id'); 
});
```

But the above code snippet is not working. Can anybody suggest better method to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, use atributes 'id' in your list

```
<li id="10" class="my-class">test-1</li>
<li id="15" class="my-class">test-2</li>
<li id="20" class="my-class">test-3</li>
```

And in javascript, this.id

```
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
 var ids = this.id; 
 alert(ids);
});
```

And include jquery.
Eg: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/7h1ecsm7/

Answer (score 4):

Try to invoke `.attr()` over `$(this)`. since `.attr()` will not be available in the prototype of a node object,

```
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
 var ids = $(this).attr('my-id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `e.currentTarget` as a selector like this.

```js
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
 var ids = $(e.currentTarget).attr("my-id");  
 alert(ids)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li my-id="10" class="my-class">test-1</li>
<li my-id="15" class="my-class">test-2</li>
<li my-id="20" class="my-class">test-3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` is a jQuery method so you should call it on jQuery object `$(this)` :

```
var ids = $(this).attr('my-id');
```

if you want javascript alternative you could use `getAttribute` :

```
var ids = e.target.getAttribute('my-id');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.my-class').on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('my-id')+' ---- '+ $(this).attr('my-id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li my-id="10" class="my-class">test-1</li>
<li my-id="15" class="my-class">test-2</li>
<li my-id="20" class="my-class">test-3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap this with jQuery then use the attr method to get the attribute you need:

```
$('.my-class').click(function() {
  var ids = $(this).attr('my-id'); 
});
```